# HD camera Issue in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04

I am using the **QCamera** class to show the camera output to **QcameraViewFinder**.
There is two camera : one is HD and other is normal.
Switching to normal camera is fast, but switching to HD cam takes some seconds and the machine is getting hanged for a while.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Comment: Does this happen in other apps?  Does this happen with other cameras?  In other words, how do you know this isn't a problem with your camera driver?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Ya, in other apps (like cheese) also the problem exists.

I have checked it on only one HD camera.

If it is problem of the driver how can be fixed,

I am using Logitech C525 HD webcam.

Is there any driver available for Ubuntu?

Comment: Both QCamera and Cheese are probably fetching video on your system through GStreamer.  Webcam support on Linux is unfortunately not always great, but you might ask the GStreamer developers if they're aware of the issue or know of any workarounds.  Regardless it doesn't sound like this question is really about programming but rather a driver issue, you'd might as well delete it.